# Prevent Amazon Chime fom defaulting to auto-start?

Tags: amazon-chime

Scummy Amazon has made this Chime thing default to setting the option of "Start Amazon Chime when computer starts" always on. Every time I invoke this POS I have to shut that option off, otherwise the craprod bytes off some of my resources. Has anybody found a solution to this hassle?

Answer (score 2):

On windows, go to your task manager (right click on your task bar and select task manager). Then click on "Startup apps" on the left pane and finally, disable Chime.com from starting up.

[image: Disable Chime from starting up automatically on windows]

Comment: No, that's not the issue. The application (I no longer use) sets itself up as auto-start whenever it is invoked. This is naughty behavior and needs to be cleaned out of the application's default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac, in System Preferences, search for "Open applications at login" and deselect from here.